# Hidden service setup

Tags: configuration, onion-services, anonymity, security, help

Planning on starting my own hidden service but would want some advice regarding the security/privacy. Looking for someone with experience to be able to tell me from A to Z (from nothing to finished product) and how to maintain the hidden service.
If you don't feel comfortable here we could for sure talk on a different platform.

Comment: What kind of onion service are you trying to run, and what security/privacy do you need?

Comment: @Steve Marketplace where only me and trusted seller are able to sell. for security/privacy am looking to build a platform where you can securely communicate and buy without having to worry about any troubles. hope i explained it well enough for you.